# How to send stdin to redis channel in realtime?

Tags: bash, redis, redis-cli

I want to send the stdout and stderr of terminal while I run a huge batch file. The batch file
echoer.sh

```sh
echo $HOME
sleep 3
echo $HOME
sleep 3
echo $HOME
# n times
```

Executing in terminal

```sh
./echoer.sh | redis-cli -x publish echoer
```

This waits for the entire execution of `echoer.sh` to finish and then send the publish command. Is there a way to publish the output as soon as you receive it?

Current Output

```sh
# command
redis-cli subscribe echoer
# output below
1) "message"
2) "echoer"
3)"/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n/home/prashant\n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xargs` , it sends each line to `echoer` channel using xargs utility.

```
 ./echoer.sh| xargs -n 1 redis-cli  publish echoer
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, read the output of your script one line at a time and then publish that line to Redis:

```
./echoer.sh | while read line ; do echo "$line" | redis-cli -x publish echoer ; done
```

Comment: Why not just `/echoer.sh | while read line; do redis-cli publish echoer "$line"; done`